# Date picker in different year month and day selector boxes using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, html, date

I would like know how to add 80 years old years from current year to select box by using ng-repeat. I already done looping for months and days and those are working fine. I want know how to do it for years according above recoverment.

JS Code:

```
app.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, min, max) {
    min = parseInt(min);
    max = parseInt(max);
    for (var i=min; i<=max; i++)
      input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<select class="custom-select" required ng-model="bd">
<option selected disabled ng-selected="true">Days</option>
<option ng-repeat="n in [] | range:1:31" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
</select>

<select class="custom-select" required ng-model="bm">
<option selected disabled ng-selected="true">Months</option>
<option ng-repeat="n in [] | range:1:12" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
</select>

<select class="custom-select" required ng-model="by">
<option selected disabled ng-selected="true">Year</option>
<option ng-repeat="n in [] | range:new Date().getFullYear()-80:new Date().getFullYear()" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest would to do another filter:

```
app.filter('yearRange', ['$filter', function($filter) {
  return function(input, range) {
    $filter('range')(input, new Date().getFullYear()-range, new Date().getFullYear());
  }
}]);
```

Call it with:

```
<option ng-repeat="n in [] | yearRange: 80" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
```

Alternatively, you can create the current year as a `$scope` variable, and call it in your filter.

Controller:

```
$scope.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
```

HTML:

```
<option ng-repeat="n in [] | range: $scope.currentYear-80:$scope.currentYear" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
```

3rd Alternative. Call `$filter` from your controller, and initialize the years array there (Make sure it's passed in):

```
$scope.years = $filter('range')([], new Date().getFullYear()-80, new Date().getFullYear());
```

Then use:

```
<option ng-repeat="n in years" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
```

Comment: code is not working for me what is your angular js version. my version is angular-1.5.8

Comment: What's it doing? I forgot a closing `]`, which should work now.